# To play videos of Kindle reader in OSX?

Tags: macos

My kindle program says that the current Kindle Reader does not support videos.
Kindle fire plays them at least.
I am not sure if iPad does so.

**Which devices are supported by the videos of Kindle?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kindle for Mac](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000464931) is specifically for reading Kindle books, and doesn't handle any other media.  On iOS, the same is available through the [Kindle app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kindle-read-books-ebooks-magazines/id302584613?mt=8).

[Amazon Cloud Player for Mac](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1001067901) is for music purchased in the MP3 store.  Again, there is an [Amazon Cloud Player app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amazon-cloud-player/id510855668?mt=8) for iOS as well.

On your Mac, Amazon Instant Video is available through the Amazon website itself.  If you have video in your library, you can access it through [Your Video Library](https://www.amazon.com/gp/video/library).  In general, though, any video you have rights to view (e.g. with Prime Instant Video), you can access by finding it on Amazon's website.  On iOS devices, you can use the [Amazon Instant Video app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amazon-instant-video/id545519333?mt=8), which also supports AirPlay for playback on an Apple TV (though Amazon does not actually have native video support on Apple TV.)

Comment: so to the question, which apple devices will play kindle video?

Comment: @Buscar Thanks for the pointer, edited.  The question is a bit hard to parse so I missed that detail the first time, as it seemed the asker's original question was more about how he could play Amazon videos on his Mac.